# French Drain inlet into/under retaining wall

Tags: drainage, exterior, retaining-wall

I have a basement egress into a weird large walkable trench that awkwardly divides my yard.  I think this was done partly following a cusp in the original landscape while solving for drainage in a brute-force way.

I aim to cap & fill most of the trench to the original topography, but I still need to solve for drainage of water near the egress.  I want to avoid having to dig even deeper or breaking the existing trench slab to maintain drainage because adding drain pipes even lower is more involved/expensive and presumably harder to get a permit for in this strictly regulated environmentally sensitive site).

I'm imagining a gravel-only channel (no cylindrical pipes) that would have inlets (about 6ft linear max width) integrated into the base of the new trench endcap retaining wall allowing water to drain under it and then just reuse the existing concrete trench slope to direct the water away.  This would allow me to minimally disturb the sensitive remaining soil.

I'm looking for plausibly permittable design prototypes that I could mimic.  To instill confidence of my plans for my county reviewers, I will need to include the necessary engineering-speak and product terms for how to design the inlet with available retaining wall systems.  Web searches overwhelm me with designs of how to drain water *out* from behind a retaining wall.  Obviously, I need to do this too, I just want it to go the long way.  Incidentally, the typical drainage behind the retaining wall will join this too.

I imagine the inlet (purple area of interest) would need to resist clogging, facilitate capture/removal of seasonal leaves and dirt, and of course be structurally robust as the base of the retaining wall end-cap section above it.  Any technical guidance, please?

[image: existing and proposed drainage]

Comment: Where will you go upon egressing?   How do you get to grade?

Comment: "Existing stairs"

Comment: Existing stairs that step down to a concrete (effectively) sidewalk that will be getting filled over?

Comment: This is a side-view.  There's the basement door with a some space to turn and ascend the stairs.  The rest of the trench is not useful so I want to fill it in to create a land-bridge between the topsides of the main grade.

Comment: If there's a place for people to go from the stairs, why can't water go there too?

Comment: Because water can't climb steps.  I accept that my terrible drawing/descriptions are somehow misleading you here, but I can't figure out how you're seeing it.  Sorry.